# Facing issue while merging existing table in snowflake with s3 stage parquet file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to execute below script:

```
MERGE INTO  data_stage.test_temp4  ex  USING (
SELECT
$1:device_attr_hk,
$1:applicationruntime_raw,
$1:devicefamily_raw,
$1:deviceprofile_raw,
$1:manufacturer_raw,
$1:model_raw,
$1:application_runtime_os,
$1:device_profile,
$1:device_family,
$1:device_platform,
$1:manufacturer,
$1:model,
$1:device_type,
$1:creation_timestamp,
$1:change_hkey
FROM  @dss.test_plus.test_plus_stage/dev/sub_solutions/test/  (file_format => 'parquet', PATTERN => '.*.parquet')

) ne ON ex.device_attr_hk = ne.device_attr_hk WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET device_attr_hk = ne.device_attr_hk, applicationruntime_raw = ne.applicationruntime_raw, devicefamily_raw = ne.devicefamily_raw, deviceprofile_raw = ne.deviceprofile_raw, manufacturer_raw = ne.manufacturer_raw, model_raw = ne.model_raw, application_runtime_os = ne.application_runtime_os, device_profile = ne.device_profile, device_family = ne.device_family, device_platform = ne.device_platform, manufacturer = ne.manufacturer,  model = ne.model,  device_platform = ne.device_platform ,  manufacturer = ne.manufacturer,  model = ne.model,  device_type = ne.device_type,  creation_timestamp = ne.creation_timestamp,  change_hkey = ne.change_hkey WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(device_attr_hk, applicationruntime_raw, devicefamily_raw, deviceprofile_raw, manufacturer_raw, model_raw, application_runtime_os, device_profile, device_family, device_platform, manufacturer, model, device_type, creation_timestamp, change_hkey) VALUES
(ne.device_attr_hk, ne.applicationruntime_raw, ne.devicefamily_raw, ne.deviceprofile_raw, ne.manufacturer_raw, ne.model_raw, ne.application_runtime_os, ne.device_profile, ne.device_family, ne.device_platform, ne.manufacturer, ne.model, ne.device_type, ne.creation_timestamp, ne.change_hkey);
commit;
```

But I am getting error: SQL compilation error: **File format 'PARQUET' does not exist or not authorized**.

**Note:** file already avialable on stage: @dss.test_plus.test_plus_stage/dev/sub_solutions/test/ And I have able to access it.

I have doubt , why I am not able to access this file an merge, is there any issue in script that written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you try using the file_format with the name 'parquet' which does not exist

I suggest you create a named file_format first and use its name in your command.

Step 1. Create a named file format, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_parquet_format
  TYPE = PARQUET;
```

Step 2. Change the line with `FROM` in your script as follows:

```sql
FROM  @dss.test_plus.test_plus_stage/dev/sub_solutions/test/  (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet')
```

Then you can try again.